# Databricks - Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I trying to execute the following code in databricks but I receive the error: `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project and a few commands: Join LeftOuter`

```
SELECT
 M.VAR_1,
 C.VAR_2,
 N.VAR_3
FROM TABLE_1 C
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 M                ON C.CONTRACT_ID = M.CONTRACT_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_3 FINREC           ON M.CODE_2 = FINREC.CODE_3
LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 N                 ON N.CODE_4 = (SELECT MAX(NN.CODE_4) 
                                                      FROM TABLE_4 NN 
                                                      WHERE NN.CODE_5 = M.CODE_5)
```

The query I am trying in databricks works fine in Oracle and I cannot understand what's the error I get and nor how to solve it. I am pretty new to databricks though

Comment: Hi,
I am facing a similar problem. If you managed to solve this, can you please post your solution